# Merge existing columns in POstgreSQL 9.1 hstore column

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 database table (let's call it MyTable) looking like this:

```
 gid | name | address | phone | colA | colB | colC | colD
------------------------------------------------------------
     |      |         |       |      |       |      |
```

I enabled in this database hstore:

```
 CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

Now, I want to create a hstore column (colH), where to store the columns colA colB colC colD, with key their name and values, their values.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN colH hstore;
```

Now, how I insert the values in the hstore column? I think INSERT would help but I do not know how to do it.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert is used to create new *rows*, not to change columns of existing rows.

You need to use `update` after adding the hstore column:

```
update mytable
   set colh = hstore('cola', cola)||hstore('colb', colb)||hstore('colc', colc)||hstore('cold', cold);
```

or - slightly more compact:

```
update mytable
    set colh = hstore(array['cola','colb','colc','cold'], array[cola,colb,colc,cold]);
```

This assumes that cola, colb, colc and cold are of type `text` or varchar. If they are not you need to cast them properly.

After that you can drop the columns you don't need any longer.

Comment: Works! Thanks! Only a typo in cold'.